# What does :: means in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I was using the code from this example: [Link](https://github.com/olahol/react-tagsinput/blob/master/example/components/autocomplete.js)

I straight copied the code from it but notice that there are serval syntax errors appear on this line:

```
return <TagsInput renderInput={autocompleteRenderInput} value={this.state.tags} onChange={::this.handleChange} />
```

These errors complain about the two columns from 'onChange={::this.handleChange}' which I have never seen before.

Should I just simply get rid of them?